# Onvif authentication

Tags: vb.net, authentication, onvif

It appears that Onvif authentication is a bit of a minefield!

I read that SOAP WS-security was deliberately not included in Microsoft Web Services so people have to code it up...

Not sure if this applies to HTTP digest as well?

Before I begin to port one of the c# code examples of the authentication over to my vb.net application, has anyone already done this?

Have there been any updated services, dlls etc that include WS-security?

I have yet to find any vb.net examples of working with ONVIF, but maybe I haven't searched hard enough yet!

Comment: did you find anything yet?

Comment: I did get this all working in the end, but it was certainly a challenge. I lot more awkward than you'd think!